# Print A4 (labelsheet) from web doesn't fill width of paper on 595px width

Tags: html, css, asp.net, printing

I know the recommended way of doing this is using a PDF-something to generate a printable PDF to have more control of the output..

But i just wonder if it can be done.. using only html and css the way i'm trying to accomplish here :

**CODE - HEAD and CSS**

```
    <html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            height: 842px;
            width: 595px;
            /*margin left/right - 3,81 %*/
            /*margin-left: 22.67px; margin-top: 22.67px; padding-right: -22.67px; margin-bottom: -22.67px*/
            /*label size : 28,57*/
            /*170 px*/
            /* to centre page on screen*/
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .lbl {
            width: 174.8px;
            /*height: 130.3px;*/
            height: 131.7px;
            border: 1px solid purple;
            float: left;
        }

        .lbl-inner {
            padding: 3px;
            display: table-cell;
            word-break: break-all;
        }

        .spc {
            width: 8.5px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

**CODE - HTML**

```
<body>
<div style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <div id="inner" style="margin: 22.67px; border: 1px dashed blue;">
        <div class="lbl"><span class="lbl-inner">123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789</span></div>
        <div class="spc">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="lbl"><span class="lbl-inner">123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789</span></div>
        <div class="spc">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="lbl"><span class="lbl-inner">123456789123456789123456789123456789123456789</span></div>
```

**Screenshot - Screenview**
[image]

**Screenshot - After print (paper)**
[image]

As you see, the content is much narrower than it should have been. 
Is there a "quick" fix for these kind of print issues for web ?

Comment: Have you tried @media print{body {height: auto; width: 100%;}}. Your body has a width of 595px; so your first div, even though it's width is 100%, it's 100% of 595px;

Comment: I will try that now :) Print Preview (in chrome) still looks the same as it did earlier though.. should it have been different ? Or... does the @media trigger when you actually print it.

Comment: Ah, your other divs also need a % width. Instead of using .spc, why not use padding?